# Set a custom domain for an azure Storage Account through an ARM template

Tags: azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to setup an ARM template to set a custom domain for an Azure storage account. I am only running this portion of my ARM template after the storage account is initially setup and a DNS record has been created, but it still fails with this error:

: The custom domain name could not be verified. CNAME mapping from myStorage.mydomain.com to .blob.core.windows.net does not exist.

I've replaced my domain in the error, but the rest is exact.  I notice that it looks suspicious since it doesn't list the name of my storage account, but the storage account is named, so I can't figure out how to affect that.  Here's the resource definition (again, the account name and domain are replaced, but all else is the same)

```
"resources": [
  {
    "name": "myStorageAccount",
    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
    "sku": {
      "name": "Standard_LRS"
    },
    "dependsOn": [],
    "tags": {
      "displayName": "Storage Account"
    },
    "kind": "BlobStorage",
    "properties":{
        "customDomain":{
        "name":"myStorage.mydomain.com",
        "useSubDomain":false
        }
    }
  }            
]
```

I can set it to the same custom domain through the Azure portal.  It validates fine there. I'm sure I could do it through a separate PowerShell script, but I prefer to do it in the ARM, so as to minimize the need for additional scripts when setting up my environment.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Will report back if I find something